# Can't log into Active Admin after pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activeadmin, migrate

I was trying to push a Rails app including `active_admin` to Heroku.

I expect to be able to log into Active Admin after pushing to Heroku

I have built a Rails app using `active_admin`. First I tried it on my `localhost`. I logged in with `admin@example.com`, set a new admin, and deleted the `admin@example.com` user. Then I pushed my app to GitHub and further to Heroku. I noticed Active Admin was not reachable on Heroku so I checked the logs and ran `heroku rake db:migrate`. Now I can switch to the login site at `/admin` but I cannot login. Neither with the `admin@example.com` nor my newly-created admin.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Fixed it with bypassing the authentication in the active_admin.rb

Comment: Why would you bypass authentication? How can that possibly be considered a solution?

Comment: @Chris i set config.current_user_method  and config.authentication_method in the active_admin.rb to false. deployed it to heroku. Went in the admin interface and created a new admin. set the methods in the .rb back and deployed it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy to Heroku your *code* gets updated on your dynos. Your *database* doesn't. Migrations must be run, e.g. via `heroku run rake db:migrate` or a [release phase command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase), and any data you want must be created.

Whatever users you've configured on your development machine won't exist on Heroku. This is a good thing.

You should be able to add the default admin user by running `heroku run rake db:seed` using the Heroku CLI tool. Alternatively, you could run `heroku run rails c` and create a user interactively.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is that in the `seeds.rb` file, the line indicates only to be used if env = development. Here's exactly what it says:

`AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') if Rails.env.development?`

In a production instance like Heroku, you'll have to use something like PSql, connect directly to the Heroku PG database for your instance, and create a user via query as this is the most secure way to do so.